# zend router issue in some directories

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have an `uploads` directory in public path, but in some projects *zend* can't understand this is a directory and not a *Controller*.

when I open this folder, *zend* shows below error to me:

```
Invalid controller specified "uploads"
```

checked `.htaccess` and have no problem.
this is my htaccess code:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 AddDefaultCharset utf-8
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf|css|js|html?|xml|txt)$">
        ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
    </FilesMatch>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.(js|css))$ plugins/smartoptimizer/?$1
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule ^(.*\.(js|css|html?|xml|txt))$ plugins/smartoptimizer/?$1
    </IfModule>
 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_expires.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf|css|js|html?|xml|txt))$ plugins/smartoptimizer/?$1
 </IfModule>

 <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf|css|js|html?|xml|txt)$">
    FileETag none
 </FilesMatch>

#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript text/css text/html text/xml
</IfModule>



#enabling gzip----------------------------
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# cache images and flash content for one month
<filesmatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</filesmatch>

# cache text, css, and javascript files for one week
<filesmatch ".(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</filesmatch>

# cache html and htm files for one day
<filesmatch ".(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
</filesmatch>

# implement minimal caching during site development
<filesmatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|js|css|pdf|swf|html|htm|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=5"
</filesmatch>

# explicitly disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
<filesmatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</filesmatch>



SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please post your htaccess file and some info about your project structure

Comment: I am done , htaccess code included

Comment: are you trying to load `http://yoursite/uploads/` in the browser? Or view a file? `http://yoursite/uploads/somefile.pdf`?

Comment: yes both of them, htaccess no have problem because work good in other projects. I think zend framework have a bug

Comment: This is a problem with your rewrite rules, it's not a ZF issue. Does the document root for your project point at the public directory?

Comment: yes, can the problem from compiled apache in server or problem is in my htaccess code?!